# Chazzanish Recordings

Tags: product-recommendation, chazzan-prayer-leader, recording, yekke

Are there any recordings of any of the old, German chazzanim singing their nusach? I know that KAYJ.net includes a nusach page, however, the recordings are somewhat lackluster (although they are an invaluable resource). My grandfather z"l, although he could have fallen into that category typically sang more of the common Eastern European and American niggunim, thus I have little to go on.

Comment: Also: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/70102

Comment: @msh210, currently that's a bit of an infinite loop

Answer (score 1):

The Dartmouth University Jewish Sound Archive has some good recordings.

Comment: Do you have an online link to this? Or is it a physical archive?

Comment: @DonielF, it's online

Comment: @Noach You should try the Jerusalem sound archive: http://web.nli.org.il/sites/nli/hebrew/pages/default.aspx