# Looking for online German (Yekke) Torah Trope practice

Tags: product-recommendation, technology, torah-reading, trop-cantillation, yekke

As a lad, I often attended a German (Yekke) shul in my neighborhood, where they used the Yekke Torah trope. My main shul sometimes used this trope during Yom Tov readings. (I.e. - the Yekke trope is used year-round in the Yekke shul, only on Yom Tov in my main shul.)

I am looking for some online recordings or practice files where I can practice this. If it is available via CD, would someone know if I can purchase this online or in a Judaic store in NYC area?

Comment: Also: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44356

Comment: DanF, I actually have a recording that was provided to me by R' Michael Friedman, chazzan of KAYJ. How would I get it to you, I don't know whether I should upload it to J.SE.

Comment: There is a sample cantillation at https://www.kayj.net/en/nusach

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt What is JSE? Perhaps another way is if I provide you with a link to my Google drive, if the file is not too big, or you can email? If we can chat, briefly, about 1 PM, or this eve 9:30 or later, that may work. Let me know, and thanks.

Comment: @DanF, bli neder, I should be online around 1pm. J.SE is one of the shorthands for Mi Yodeya.

Comment: @DanF, sorry, I dropped the ball.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38155/discussion-between-danf-and-noach-mi-frankfurt).

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt do you still have this available? I am interested as well. Particularly haftarah if you have that also

Comment: @yitznewton, I do.